# Passing a resolved SAS macro variable through R

Tags: r, macros, sas, parameter-passing

I'm generating a PDF that goes through quite a journey. First, a SAS macro creates a .txt file which is read into R, which is then output into a final PDF. I would like to run my R program through SAS, but I need to pass a filepath referenced in SAS to R. I've looked into using the 'rawr' package, but this isn't passing *resolved* SAS macro variables through R. Any insight would be greatly appreciated. I'd explore any avenue.
Thanks!

Comment: Please show an example of the code illustrating the problem.  Sounds like your writing SAS code, and invoking R from SAS.  Should be fine.

Comment: Do you have SAS/IML licensed?  You can run R directly in IML and pass macros into R variables.

Comment: Quentin, I'm not sure that I did a good job explaining what I'm trying to do. I'm familiar with invoking R through SAS. However, I'm not familiar with passing a resolved SAS macro variable to R. Essentially, I need to extract a SAS macro variable to be placed in the middle of my Rmarkdown code. This macro variable is a filepath, and it changes dynamically. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 3):

As Quentin says, you can pass information from SAS to R by using the SAS/IML interface.  On the SUBMIT line you can put any SAS/IML variable and that value of that variable will be substituted (as text) into the SAS program before SAS sends the program to R. [The SAS/IML documentation contains examples.](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/imlug/68150/HTML/default/viewer.htm#imlug_r_sect011.htm)

If you want to send a macro value into R, **first** store it into a SAS/IML variable, **then** pass the value of the SAS/IML variable to R, as follows:

```
%let path = C:/Temp/Path1;
proc iml;
path1 = "&path";   /* copy to character string */
submit path1 / R; 
    theSASpath <- "&path1"
    theSASpath
endsubmit;
```

If the value of the macro variable changes while the program is running, just rerun the "path = " and SUBMIT statements to update the R copy of the path.